# mongodb conditional stages or conditional pipeline in aggregation

Tags: mongodb

there's the prices collection.

```
[{  
   "_id":"...683d",
   "brandId":"...f31c",
   "model":"N5",
   "pwId":"...1b67",
   "number":50
}, {  
   "_id":"...683e",
   "brandId":"...f31c",
   "model":"base",
   "pwId":"...1b67",
   "number":40
}, ...]
```

there's the items collection.

```
[{  
   "_id":"...31aa",
   "pwId":"...1b67",
   "brandId":"...f31c",
   "model":"abc",
   "series": "N5",
   "bms": "yyn"
}, ...]
```

I'd like to get the price of items and the steps are:

1. check `item.bms`, if `bms === 'yyn'`, use sub-pipeline-a, otherwise, use sub-pipeline-b;
2. let's look at sub-pipeline-a, sub-pipeline-b could be similar.
   2.1 match price with three conditons, `pwId + brandId + model`, if found, go no further;
   2.2 if not found, try `pwId + brandId + series`(`item.series` as `price.model)`, if found, go no further;
   2.3 if still not found, try `pwId + brandId + 'base'`(`'base'` as `price.model`);
3. combine the result of both sub-pipeline-a and sub-pipeline-b.

For step 1, I'm using a `$facet` stage. For step 2.1 through 2.3, I'm running 3 `$lookup`s one after another, which is obviously a waste of resources.

How to decide whether to run 2.2 based on result of 2.1?